# Entity Framework second level cache

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, caching, entity-framework-6

I want to use [`EntityFramework.Cache`](https://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/using-second-level-cache-in-entity-framework-6-1-applications) for one of my tables, but I can not find any information about how does it work with live data and relationships?

I want to know if I add some data to my table or the relation tables does it understand it and re-cache table again or the result could be stale?

Does anyone work with any Entity Framework second level cache?

Comment: please refer following links-
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394143.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/435142/Entity-Framework-Second-Level-Caching-with-DbConte

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A cache normally caches entities (Detached from the context) and re-uses the same result as long as the cache is not expired.

If you change the query, a new result is cached (even if it returns the same entity key) since relations could have been changed.

Here is an alternative to the cache you are currently using:

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project EntityFramework Plus on [GitHub](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

EF+ Query Cache allows to cache query with tag, expiration and cache control.

Documentation: [Entity Framework - Second Level Cache](http://entityframework-plus.net/query-cache)

**EDIT: Answer comment**

> if data has been updated, and new information must be served up that we can remove specific entities from cache

For EF6, we have the built-in `IsAutoExpireCacheEnabled`  option:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    QueryCacheManager.IsAutoExpireCacheEnabled = true;
}
```

For EF Core, we didn't find out how to make it happen yet.

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to share Cache between Context Instances?

Comment: @user756037, if you talk about the EF+ Query Cache, it already works between context instances since items are detached.

Comment: @JonathanMagnan Does this enable granular cache invalidation? It's vitally important for reliability if data has been updated, and new information must be served up that we can remove specific entities from cache.